# Gradle jar will run inside of intellij but not outside as a standalone

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

After building my gradle jar within intellij, my project will run perfectly fine. If I try to then move that jar to my desktop and run it using the command "java -jar ProjectName.jar" it throws and error "Cannot find or load main class main"

I'm painfully aware that this question has been asked multiple times on this website as I've spent hours trying to fix it. Ever since I reinstalled Intellij I have been having this issue. I've tried making a fat jar and excluding META-INF, I tried creating a whole new project and creating a jar within that project. I also tried to use a recent iteration of this project which did run as a standalone and had no luck.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'PantryDatabase'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile(
            [group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-bigquery', version: '1.74.0'],
            [group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '9.0.8'],
            [group: 'me.xdrop', name: 'fuzzywuzzy', version: '1.2.0']
    )
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "Main"
    }
    from configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) }
}

task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = 'Pantry_Database'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar

    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }
}
```

Class Files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPjdD.jpg

Error Message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0mbt.jpg

Comment: JavaFX is missing in the runtime you are using. Either install it or bundle. Google "bundle javafx" for details.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have javaFX installed since it comes with Java SE 11.0.4, am I missing something?

Comment: JavaFX is no longer bundled. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.